# Draw a circle on a PNG file in Java

Tags: java, image, file, awt

I am trying to read a PNG, draw a circle and write the image to the same or a different file. But the new image is identical to the input image. What am I missing? Thank you.

```
File file = new File("Screenshot.png");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);

Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
g2d.fillOval(center.x - radius, center.y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
g2d.dispose();

File outFile = new File("new.png");
ImageIO.write(image, "png", outFile);
```

EDIT: I did find that linked question myself, but still do not understand how to modify the image I read from file using ImageIO. The example from the answer showing there is creating a `BufferedImage` from the `JPanel`.

Comment: Is image being modified? I just see it reading, then writing out but no modifying.

Comment: you are drawing your circle on a separate image. So when you save the first image back it's unmodified. Is this a mistake?

Comment: Is `screenshotImage` supposed to be `image` on line 4?

Comment: @Eric G, yes it was a mistake. fixed.

Comment: Draw the image to the `Graphics2D` before you draw your circle, and then save the `Graphics2D` (not the original *image*).

Comment: Have you tried printing the values of `center` and `radius` to make sure they're valid and within the size of the image?

Comment: Is the `g2d.dispose()` causing the changes to be removed before it gets written?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, how do I save the `Graphics2D` to a new image?

Comment: @VGR, thank you! I was calling it in a test with a very large screenshot image, and a very small radius.